# Seven cards are selected at random from a standard deck of 52 cards...

Tags: probability, card-games

Seven cards are selected at random from a standard deck of 52 cards, what is the probability there will be no pairs? (pairs means two cards of the same denomination and same color)

Comment: ... what have you tried?

Comment: I tried 13x3+4x2 from the fact that 13 clubs and spades and such are in a standard deck of cards and arrived at 47 but I don't know if its right

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ From your definition of pair (which is not the standard definition of what a pair is), each card only has one pair. Split the cards into $2$ decks, $26$ cards each, so that each card in deck $1$ has a pair in deck $2$. How many ways can you pick $7$ cards so that there are no pairs?

Comment: Well, you can select seven pairs and choose which card to keep from each...